# Replace an Image in WordPress Posts

Tags: php, wordpress, image

I tried to write a PHP snippet to replace an image in a WordPress post, based on the sample code https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_insert_attachment/ as below:

```
<?php 

include "wp-load.php";

// $filename should be the path to a file in the upload directory.
$filename = 'C:/wamp64/www/blogs/wp-content/uploads/2024/03/test.jpg';

// The ID of the post this attachment is for.
$parent_post_id = 14;

// Check the type of file. We'll use this as the 'post_mime_type'.
$filetype = wp_check_filetype( basename( $filename ), null );

// Get the path to the upload directory.
$wp_upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();

// Prepare an array of post data for the attachment.
$attachment = array(
    'guid'           => $wp_upload_dir['url'] . '/' . basename( $filename ), 
    'post_mime_type' => $filetype['type'],
    'post_title'     => preg_replace( '/\.[^.]+$/', '', basename( $filename ) ),
    'post_content'   => '',
    'post_status'    => 'inherit',
    'ID' => 15
);

// Insert the attachment.
$attach_id = wp_insert_attachment( $attachment, $filename, $parent_post_id );

// Make sure that this file is included, as wp_generate_attachment_metadata() depends on it.
require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php' );

// Generate the metadata for the attachment, and update the database record.
$attach_data = wp_generate_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $filename );
wp_update_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $attach_data );

//set_post_thumbnail( $parent_post_id, $attach_id );
?>
```

However, when debugging it, wp_update_attachment_metadata will always raise an exception and go to WP_Fatal_Error_Handler::handle() function.

After the execution, the new image does NOT replace the image attachment with ID = 15, instead, it becomes the featured image, which is not desired.

**Update**

After execution, the script will always go to WP_Fatal_Error_Handler::handle() to deal possible errors, even if there are no errors. So now everything is fine.